# Vue async components are loading without delay regardless of the the 'delay' parameter

Tags: asynchronous, vuejs2, vue-component, async-components

I am using [Advanced-Async-Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Advanced-Async-Components) to load `async component` after loading of the app. So I have tried the following code:

**Index.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="">
        <Async></Async>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    // async component
    import LoadComp from '@/components/Loading'
    import ErrorComp from '@/components/Error'
    const Async = () => ({
        // The component to load. Should be a Promise
        component: import('@/components/Async'),
        // A component to use while the async component is loading
        loading: Load,
        // A component to use if the load fails
        error: ErrorComp,
        // Delay before showing the loading component. Default: 200ms.
        delay: 4000, // <--- this is not effecting the loading of component
        // The error component will be displayed if a timeout is
        // provided and exceeded. Default: Infinity.
        timeout: 3000
    })

export default {
    components: {
        Async
    }
}
</script>
```

**Async.vue**

```
<template lang="html">
    <div class="">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, con .... very larger string/data
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
}
</script>

<style lang="css">
</style>
```

The above code works fine but it has no effect of `delay` parameter (Index.vue). According to official docs `delay` is **Delay before showing the loading component**. It should load the component after `4000ms` but it loads instantly.

> **Why is this happening?**

Is there any other way to achieve this apart from using `setTimeout`?

**Additional Info**

I used `webpack` template to build the project using `vue-cli`

```
Vue version : ^2.4.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the `delay` option sets the amount of delay in milliseconds before showing the *loading* component, which is the component you have specified via the `loading` option to display while the *async* component is loading (the documentation is poorly-worded on this one).

In the below example, two async components are loaded after one second. The first has no delay and the its loading component (`LoadingComponent`) will display immediately. The second has a `delay` of `500`, meaning that after half a second, it will display its loading component.

```js
const LoadingComponent = { template: `<h1>Loading...</h1>` }
const NumberBoxComponent = { template: `<h1>123123</h1>` }

const AsyncComponent1 = () => ({
  component: new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(NumberBoxComponent)
    }, 1000)
  }),
  loading: LoadingComponent,
})

const AsyncComponent2 = () => ({
  component: new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(NumberBoxComponent)
    }, 1000)
  }),
  loading: LoadingComponent,
  delay: 500
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    'async-component1': AsyncComponent1,
    'async-component2': AsyncComponent2
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <async-component1></async-component1>
  <async-component2></async-component2>
</div>
```

If you want to delay the actual loading of the async component, you should use `setTimeout`.

Comment: Thanks buddy, although i have tried `setTimeout` already, just wanted to try better way. But now it's only way I think. Just one question, is setTimeout triggered after the `delay` time? What if the `setTimeout` in above code is very less as compared to `delay`

Comment: The `setTimeout` function in the above example is triggered after the delay has been specified. If the component loads in less time than the delay amount, the loading component just won't be shown.