# Vue Dynamic Component from Promise

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I've followed the Vue documentation and stumbled upon [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Handling-Loading-State):

```
const AsyncComponent = () => ({
  // The component to load (should be a Promise)
  component: import('./MyComponent.vue'),
  // A component to use while the async component is loading
  loading: LoadingComponent,
  // A component to use if the load fails
  error: ErrorComponent,
  // Delay before showing the loading component. Default: 200ms.
  delay: 200,
  // The error component will be displayed if a timeout is
  // provided and exceeded. Default: Infinity.
  timeout: 3000
})
```

I tried imlementing such a component, and it worked well when the 'component' property was a `new Promise` for a simple component, however I can't get it to work with an `import` statement (like in the example).

The thing is, I have no idea what I should write in `'MyComponent.vue'`. Here is my current code:

MyComponent.vue:

```
<template>
  <!-- Components with bindings and events -->
</template>

<script>
  // Regular component, works well when imported directly without a promise
  const mainComponent = {
    name: "LoadedCategorySelect",
    data() {
      return {
        categories,
        // ...
      };
    },
    methods: {
      onCatChange(a) { // bound to v-on
        // ..
        this.$emit('newcat', this.somedata);
      },
      onSubCatChange(a) {
        // Same as above
      }
    }
  };

  export default new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Async work
        fetch('http://someurl.com/slug')
          .then((data) => {
            // ...
            resolve(mainComponent);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            reject(error);
          });
    }
  );
</script>
```

With this code, the component renders, but the events aren't registered among other things. I get a lot of errors like:
`Property or method "onSubCatChange" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property`

What did I miss? Thank you

PS: I'm using Vue 2.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are exporting a Promise from your component, which is simply wrong.

You don't have to, and shouldn't, change anything about the component itself. it should export a component options object as usual, then the async wrapper that you took from the guide should work as it is:

```
// MyComponent.vue
<script>
  export default {
    name: "LoadedCategorySelect",
    data() {
      return {
        categories,
        // ...

const AsyncComponent = () => ({
  // The component to load (should be a Promise)
  component: import('./MyComponent.vue'),
  // A component to use while the async component is loading
  loading: LoadingComponent,
  // A component to use if the load fails
  error: ErrorComponent,
  // Delay before showing the loading component. Default: 200ms.
  delay: 200,
  // The error component will be displayed if a timeout is
  // provided and exceeded. Default: Infinity.
  timeout: 3000
})
```

That's the good thing about this: The component doesn't have to be changed in any way to work as such an advanced async component.

Edit: In reply to your comment:

if you want to wrap async data loading into this, you can - but it's not pretty and I never found  a need to do this, but you might. the important thing is that the function has to return a promise that ultimately resolves to the component object.

```
//...
component: () => new Promise(resolve => {
  const aComponent = import('./MyComponent.vue').then(c => c.default)
  const aData = fetch()....
  Promise.all(aComponent, aDdata).then(([component, data]) => {
    // dosomething with  data
    // then resolve the component: 
    resolve(component)
  })
})
```

Comment: That's what I did in the first place, and it worked. But then where do I put my async operations? I want the loading to end in a fetch() callback. Then there is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46606436/3001271) which uses Promise for the component, and the doumentation says that the component to load should be a promise..